# docmosis - relative link to file

Tags: docmosis

I try to create a report (PDF/WORD) using docmosis.

In my report, I would like one of the fields to point to a file that resides relatively to the output-report. Is it possible? I saw [the documentation](https://www.docmosis.com/resources/examples/technical/hyperlinks.html) that says I have to add to the template the prefix `link:`, e.g. `<<link:linkToFile>>` so docmosis understands this is a link. However, in the output report this links to a directory which does not even exist under %TMP% folder (C:\Users\ohadr\AppData\Local\Temp...).

Is there a way to add a link to file with docmosis? And how about relative file?

Answer (score 0):

The `<<link:abc>>` directive is intended for external links which can be to files to download etc.   Currently it will not reference any **relative** content/file.